# Sum of account balance for accounts with different currencies in Java

Tags: java, sql

I am having performance issues while calculating the sum of account balances for the account with different currencies.Currently I am processing each record and converting amount of it into an amount in equivalent currency.

How can i improve performance fro this? One solution i have thought of is writing a demon class to do all this an background and save it in separate table and get the result directly from there.Please suggest me any other approach if u have in your mind.

Comment: Read please [http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

If your data is stored in a relational database, run a SQL query which does a `SUM( amount )` and a `GROUP BY currencyCode`.

Answer (score 1):

Compute aggregate function SUM on amount after grouping by currency and then do the conversion on the total amount for each currency.This way you wont have to process each record individually and hence code performance will get improved.